# I can not get Apache Lucenein queries to work in WSO2 DAS Data Explorer

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I'm trying to query a DAS table with the Data Explorer but no matter what I put in for the query it returns nothing. If I leave it blank it returns all the rows. I'm using the default H2 database in my example.

[My tables data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYzB2.png)

[Query by attribute name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVsxS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fields that you want to query need to be indexed (via the Event Persistence Configuration configuration of the stream).  See https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Configuring+Indexes for the details.